# My Own Git with User Management

Tags: android, git, github, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have this Android Source code that is about 12G big.
Therefore, Github does not support it.
To use Github, I was thinking about using Google Repo or Submodule to link the folders together but that would require too much work.  I would need to create a lot of repositories and maintain them since there are hundreds of folders in different sizes.  In addition, some of the files are bigger than 100mb.

Hence, I am back to creating my S3 git to store the files.  I would upload the files and set the whole folder to git with EC2 (most likely use Git Annex to store the big File and Jgit to push).

But, I preferred the Github interface and feature where we can set the project to public and private and invite the authorized one to work on the project.  It also would be a pain to manage all the users in the back-end (S3).

So, is there any service or software out there that have user management and interface for private server git that's similar to github?  Is there any other solutions?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few notes:

1. Git repository (can) but is not a good choice for 12GB repository.
   If you have a lot of binaries inside you consider using [Git **L**arge **F**ile **S**torage](https://git-lfs.github.com/) solution

> So, is there any service or software out there that have user management and interface for private server git that's similar to github?

There are few other services as well, but again **12GB** is something that git might have troubles to handle.

- Bitbucket - https://bitbucket.org/
- gitLab    - https://about.gitlab.com/

and few others.

Comment: Would you recommend me to break down the whole android Source code into multiple one?  So far, the large files are Kernel, prebuilt, external software (applications), framework ...
The files would be scattered and It would be hard for others to clone them.

Comment: Yep. exactly. use submodule or sub-trees.

Answer (score 1):

Check out AWS [CodeCommit](https://aws.amazon.com/codecommit/).  It is a way of hosting git using AWS.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to roll your own Github like server that will do all that under your control. I would have to give another +1 to [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/).

It's basically a self-hosted version of Github and will let you do everything you need on your own servers under your control.